# R: gsub keep the space between characters in a string without removing

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a string that  with numeric characters between them.

```
TestString = "white tiger roars.12.03.001-fast horse runs13.15.01.001-cat is useless 11.01.09.001-dog barks22.07.01.001"
```

I wan't it to look like

```
"white tiger roars-fast horse runs-cat is useless-dog barks"
```

With my approach till now, I am not able to  retain the space between the words.

```
gsub("[^a-z-]", "", TestString) 
#"whitetigerroars-fasthorseruns-catisuseless-dogbarks"
```

Comment: just add a space? `"[^a-z -]"`

Comment: or `gsub("\\d*[.]*", "", TestString)`

Comment: That's so simple. Thanks

Comment: That will result in "useless -dog barks" at the end, which is different from the expected outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gsub("\\s?(\\d+|\\.)","","white tiger roars.12.03.001-fast horse runs13.15.01.001-cat is useless 11.01.09.001-dog barks22.07.01.001")
[1] "white tiger roars-fast horse runs-cat is useless-dog barks"
```